# Не могу понять где ошибка (Python, aiogram)

Tags: python, aiogram, импорт, рефакторинг

**Доброго времени суток :)**

**Кода очень много, поэтому -> [ссылка на github](https://github.com/pipbibqiq/MIDO_bot)**

**Суть проблемы:**

1. Запускаем файл **main.py**
2. Открывается меню **ikb_mido**, нажимаем на кнопку **ib_mido_poit**
3. Программа переходит в меню **ikb_poit_course_selection** (путь poit/poit_course_selection.py)
4. В открывшемся меню при нажатии на кнопку **ib_poit_1st_course** (2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th аналогично) ничего не происходит. Хотя по моей (*скорее всего ошибочной*) логике программа должна была перейти в меню **ikb_poit_1st_course** (путь poit/poit_1st_course.py)

**Бот запускается, ошибок не выдаёт.**

Изночально данный бот был написан в одном файле main.py и всё работало корректно. Проблема вызникла при "рефакторинге", поэтому и суть её скорее всего в этом. Возможно я ещё не до конца понимаю принципы работы import-а в Python.

**Очень надеюсь, что мне тут помогут :)**

**Заранее спасибо!**

Comment: для понимания проблемы требуется предоставить хотя бы минимальный код.

Comment: Вряд ли кто-то будет запускать много вашего кода, а вот ошибка которую Вы получаете в вопросе увеличит шансы на ответ